# Changing gsuite signature with apps script returns "isDefault cannot be toggled to false"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Trying to set a signature for users using Google Apps Script. I've set up a service account and made sure the scopes are right, but when I test the code it returns the following error:

> "error": {
>     "errors": [
>      {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "invalidArgument",
>       "message": "isDefault cannot be toggled to false"
>      }
>     ],
>     "code": 400,
>     "message": "isDefault cannot be toggled to false"
>    }
>   }

Code is as below:

```
function setUserSignature() {
      var resource ={
  "sendAsEmail": "email@mycompany.be",
  "displayName": "Name Lastname",
  "replyToAddress": "email@mycompany.be",
  "signature": "Test Signature",
  "isDefault": true,
  "treatAsAlias": true
}


var service = serviceAccount("serviceaccount@mydomain.be");
service.reset();
if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var options = {
      "muteHttpExceptions":true,
"method":"PUT",
"headers": {"authorization": "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken()},
      "body":resource


}
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+ 'email@mycompany.be' +'/settings/sendAs/'+'email@alias.be';
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
        Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else is having the same problem:

Apparently using PATCH instead of PUT solved the issue.